# Toggle off the Sublime Text 2 build bar?

Tags: sublimetext2

Let's say your editing a ruby file and you run it with

```
Cmd+B
```

Then the output comes in the white "build bar" (or console window). How do you toggle it off once your done looking at it?

Comment: Pressing the ESC key works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just press the `Esc` key to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually close it just by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>. If you have clicked someplace else, you might need to click back in the Build pane first.